# Trying to open recently viewed tab hangs iOS app for a several seconds

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Trying to open recently viewed tab hangs iOS app for a several seconds.

> [image: recently]

Probably this occurred due retrieving too many items.

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: I just counted 25 seconds

Comment: @Cai it depends on actual count of items I think. And CPU speed :)

Comment: Sure. 25 seconds is a long time though, and I'd bet an iPhone 4 or 5 is significantly slower than my 6S.

Comment: @Cai let's go shopping for newest iDevice to use the app!

Comment: It's called "History" in the iPhone menu and I was able to repro on my iPhone 6.  Took about 16 seconds for content to appear and 5 more after that for the UI to become responsive again.  Something must be locking the main thread.

Comment: Is this happening every time or just the first time?

Comment: @BrianNickel every time when I switch to this tab from another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.4, shipping in February.

There was a performance regression in the way we calculate row heights so the most questions in your history, the slower it gets.

Comment: Has 1.6.4 been delayed? Version is still 1.6.3.  iPad 2 mini here, the problem still exists as of 24 March.  Takes about 60 seconds to display history and another 10 to respond to any input (taps, scrolling).  Then tapping on an entry takes 10 seconds to display, and 10 seconds to return to the history list.  Even exiting history by tapping a site icon on the site bar takes 10 seconds to leave history.

Comment: @ExUmbris Oops, I completely forgot about this.  Sorry.  Just submitted to the store.